# Inverted normals are barely visible in 2.8 version

Tags: 3d-view, normals, matcaps

Is there any way to make inverted normals more visible like in 2.7 version.
I tried diferent 'Studio' setups and matcaps, they dont help much.
Surely i could check 'Backface culling' but I would prefer not to.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could enable Face Orientation in the overlay pop-over.

[image]

After this you can edit the colors in the Preferences > Themes > 3d viewport > face orientation front / back
[image]

I use an invisible front color by setting alpha to 0 and the back color to red, slightly visible with alpha 0.2.

Comment: thank you, not exactly what i was looking for but that something

Comment: I know, the colors are over the top... I think this could be a good idea on how to improve it: https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Xqcbbc/

Comment: yeah, good proposal

Answer (score 0):

You can also identify them using X Ray. That can be felt closer to 2.79 look.

[image]

And in object mode:

[image]